# how to hide enum's "available value" in Swagger 2.0?

Tags: swagger-ui

my conf looks something like:

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  version: "1.0.0"
  title: "Users API"

definitions:
  Users:
    type: 'string'
    enum: &USERS [...huge list...]

...
 - in: "formData"
   name: "users"
   description: "Can search for these usernames"
   enum: *USERS
...
```

The issue in the UI is that I have a very long / non-readable list under `Available Values:..... list of all *USERS ....`

I can't seem to find in the docs how to hide, anyone know ?